# Абсолютно позиционируемый элемент не игнорирует margin/padding родителя

Tags: css, position, absolute

Почему элемент с `position: absolute;` не игнорирует margin/padding родителя с `position: static;`?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container-static {
  width: 1160px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.block-absolute {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: brown;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-static">
    <div class="block-absolute"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: Абсолютно позиционируемый элемент внутри родителя-контейнера]

Comment: Абсолютное позиционирование делается относительно "ближайшего" родителя с `position` отличным от `static`... В твоем примере нет родителей с такими характеристиками - т.ч. элемент позиционируется относительно всего документа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему элемент с position: absolute; не игнорирует margin/padding родителя с position: static;?

Дело в том что ты не указал элементу "как ему позиционироваться"... Потому он "встал" по умолчанию.

Если указать ему "как нужно позиционироваться" - все будет без "учета" такого родителя.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container-static {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.block-absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: brown;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-static">
    <div class="block-absolute"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```